# 10k hot spare disk for 15k RAID 10?

Tags: raid

I ordered a Dell PowerEdge R640 together with 4x 600GB 15k SAS harddisks with the intention to create a RAID 10.

To my surprise, the system already had a 600GB harddisk in, which is only 10k rpm however.

Can I use this 10k harddisk as hot spare for the RAID without it decreasing performance during normal operation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can: an hotspare disk is not used during normal (ie: non degraded) operation. Based on the power/performance profile of your PERC card, a hotspare disk can even be powered off (or, better, spunoff) during normal operation.